# Pointer and malloc issue

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

I am fairly new to C and am getting stuck with arrays and pointers when they refer to strings.  I can ask for input of 2 numbers (ints) and then return the one I want (first number or second number) without any issues.  But when I request names and try to return them, the program crashes after I enter the first name and not sure why.

In theory I am looking to reserve memory for the first name, and then expand it to include a second name.  Can anyone explain why this breaks?

Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



void main ()
{
    int NumItems = 0;

    NumItems += 1;
    char* NameList = malloc(sizeof(char[10])*NumItems);
    printf("Please enter name #1: \n");
    scanf("%9s", NameList[0]);
    fpurge(stdin);

    NumItems += 1;
    NameList = realloc(NameList,sizeof(char[10])*NumItems);
    printf("Please enter name #2: \n");
    scanf("%9s", NameList[1]);
    fpurge(stdin);

    printf("The first name is: %s",NameList[0]);
    printf("The second name is: %s",NameList[1]);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You can't have a `void` function returning 0; but `main()` should always be declared returning `int` in the first place.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan.  I made that change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that your problem is in this code:

```
scanf("%9s", NameList[0]);
```

The problem here is that `scanf` requires that the argument you provide as a location to store the result must be a pointer.  If you provide something that isn't a pointer, `scanf` will treat it as though it is and essentially write memory to a random location, crashing the program.

Fixing this requires two steps.  First, you'll want to change your declaration of `NameList` so that it's no longer a `char *`.  The reason is that a `char *` is a *single* string, whereas you want an *array* of strings.  This would be defined as a `char **`, a pointer to an array of `char *`s.  This might look like this:

```
char** NameList;
```

Next, you'll need to allocate storage space for the strings.  This is tricky and a bit subtle because you have to do two allocations.  First, you need to allocate space for the array itself, which you could do like this:

```
NameList = malloc (sizeof(char*) * NumItems);
```

This allocates an array of pointers to characters, but it doesn't actually set up the pointers in those arrays to point to valid memory locations.  To fix this, you'll want to then iterate across this array and set all of its elements to be pointers to buffers large enough to hold your strings - in this case, buffers of length 10:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < NumItems; ++i)
    NameList[i] = malloc (10); // Space for 10 characters
```

Now, you can call

```
scanf("%9s", NameList[0]);
```

Because `NameList[0]` is a `char *` pointing to the buffer into which the characters should be written.

One more comment on your code - rather than allocating an array of one element and then reallocating it to an array of two elements later on, consider just allocating all the space up-front.  It's a bit clearer.  Also, since you're now dealing with a buffer of `char *`s, each of which needs to be initialized to point to its own buffer, if you do incremental allocations you'll need to be sure to initialize all of the new `char *`s you allocate to point to a buffer somewhere.  If you do this one step at a time there's a good chance you'll forget to set up the pointers and cause a crash, whereas if you do it up front there's no such risk.

When it comes time to free the dynamically-allocated memory, you'll need to run the allocation process in reverse, first freeing the dynamically-allocated buffers for the strings, then freeing the top-level buffer.  For example:

```
for (i = 0; i < NumItems; ++i)
    free (NameList[i]);
free (NameList);
```

This is necessary because `free` doesn't work recursively.  You need to explicitly deallocate all the memory that you allocate.

Note that you do **not** write the code like this:

```
free (NameList);
for (i = 0; i < NumItems; ++i)
    free (NameList[i]);
```

This will cause all sorts of Bad Things at runtime because if you free the top-level array first, then as you try iterating over its contents freeing the pointers, you'll be reading memory that you no longer own.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great explanation, but some code to show how to `free` the memory as well would be good.

Comment: @templatetypedef Thanks for the great explanation and reminding me to use free().  I managed to get it working using a bit different code but I think your char** is probably correct and mine just happened to work out of luck. 'NumItems += 1;
 char* NameList[10];
 NameList[NumItems-1] = malloc(sizeof(char[10])*NumItems);
 printf("Please enter name #1: \n");
 scanf("%9s", NameList[0]);'
I was using the [NumItems-1] since the goal was to be able to do this in a loop where I do not know total # of names at outset.

Comment: malloc(10) is not platform independent and hurts readability. I think malloc(sizeof(char) * 10) would be preferred.

Comment: @Piva- In know that in C++ `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1.  Is this not true in C?  I have a draft C spec in which it's stated that `sizeof(char)` must be 1, and so the `malloc` should be fine.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: @templatetypedef I don't think you are mistaken. I would doubt that any architecture uses any value other than 1 for a char. It just seems a bad idea to require that the reader knows that char always uses 1 byte, and that you knew that and it was your intention.

Comment: I also see that I do not nee the "*NumItems" in the line ` NameList[NumItems-1] = malloc(sizeof(char[10])*NumItems) ` and that it actually over allocates for one string.  I was originally trying to just extend the block once a new name needed to be added.  But now it seems the pointer just moves along by 10 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Your NameList variable is a char *, which is a pointer to a single string.  (char is a single character, char * is a single string, char ** is an array of strings.)

When you use NameList[ 1], you are actually indexing the second *character* of the string, not the second string itself.

You should instead allocate an *array* of strings, something like this:

```
  char (*NameList)[10];
  NameList = malloc(10*sizeof(char)*NumItems);
```

Edit: Fixed some compile errors.  [(Sample code.)](http://codepad.org/f830mxIg)  Note that the sizeof(char) isn't really needed, as it's always 1.  Nice to be explicit, though.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot.  One quick edit I made was adding the & operator to my scanf which actually prevents it from giving me an error but as you said the output included the first letter of the first name and then the full second name.  So the second scanf  overwrote the first when my intent was to put it directly after.

Comment: @Eric Pi- I could be wrong about this, but isn't this code illegal?  `NameList` is an array, and you can't assign an array a value.

Comment: @template: You may well be right. Your answer of first allocating the array of pointers, then allocating each string in a loop is almost certainly a better approach.  I was trying to surgically repair the sample code with the least change possible.  I'm going to compile and verify now...

Comment: template is right, but I think you could get away with something like `char *NameList[] = {malloc(sizeof(char[10])), malloc(sizeof(char[10]))};` but NameList is now statically sized and on the stack.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections.  I believe I have fixed the issue.  It now allocates NumItem blocks of 10 bytes each.  I tested quickly on compiler, and seems to work properly.  As before, allocating separate array of pointers + allocating each string is certainly a good alternate approach.

Comment: I think that's still not right. `NameList` is declared as a pointer to char arrays of size 10, but you're allocating memory as if it was the char arrays itself. `NameList[0]` should refer to a char[10] array, so the allocation should be `malloc(sizeof(char**) * NumItems)` (or actually to be 100% clearly safe : `malloc(sizeof(char(*)[10]) * NumItems)`). Then you would have to go and declare or allocate the arrays themselves.

Comment: I think it's correct: I'm simply allocating 100 chars of memory in a single block, rather than 10 allocations of 10 chars each.  When you index NameList[3], you are 30 bytes into the block, etc.  Test the code link for yourself.

Comment: I guess I was mistaken, because trying it out and inspecting it with gdb showed that it did allocate 50 bytes of memory right at the address that indexing the variable referred to. Pointers to arrays have a tendency to throw me off, because I generally don't use them too often. Also looking at my comment above, I think the type I took the `sizeof` in the second `malloc` was actually an array of pointers returning chars... What would be the proper way to refer to that type, `char(*[10])`?

Answer (score 1):

If you need a 2d array of chars (an array in which every element is an array of char s), you are allocating memory in the wrong way. Correct way would be:

```
int main(){

int i;
int NumItems = 2;

/* Alocate a variable which every position points to an array of character */
char ** NameList = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *) * NumItems);

/* For each position, allocate an array of 10 characters */
for(i = 0; i < NumItems; i++){
    NameList[i] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
}

printf("Please enter name #1: \n");
scanf("%s", NameList[0]);

printf("Please enter name #2: \n");
scanf("%s", NameList[1]);

printf("The first name is: %s",NameList[0]);
printf("The second name is: %s",NameList[1]);

/* Free allocated memory. Always a good practice and prevents memory leaks. */
for(i = 0; i < NumItems; i++){
    free(NameList[i]);
}
free(NameList);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Wasn't really part of the question was it? I'll fix it anyway, thanks.

Comment: thanks.  I have to really burn using free() into my own memory.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider just using stack space instead of using `malloc` and dynamically allocating heap space:

```
#define NumItems 2
char NameList[NumItems][10];

printf("Please enter name #1: \n");
scanf("%9s", NameList[0]);

printf("Please enter name #2: \n");
scanf("%9s", NameList[1]);

printf("The first name is: %s",NameList[0]);
printf("The second name is: %s",NameList[0]);
```

Generally, unless you have a need for dynamically sized arrays, it's much much easier to use plain arrays.